# how to rename view column in oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus

Good evening

Hello everyone

How to rename view column in oracle.

i have two table 
and create view of this table. can we rename of view column.

Comment: Of course you can. What have you tried so far? Please update your question to include an example view along with what you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

You can't modify the name of a column in an existing view; there is no `alter view rename ...` clause similar to `alter table rename ...`.

You will need to drop and recreate the view. When you recreate it you can either specify the view column names explicitly, with whatever names you want, e.g.:

```
create view your_view (new_name) as select old_name from your_table;
```

or use column aliases in the view query, e.g.:

```
create view your_view as select old_name as new_name from your_table;
```